# Unique solutions of given an initial condition proof ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This is on our study guide for an upcoming test, and none of us have an idea how to answer it.

> Show that if $A(t)$ is an $n \times n$ matrix with continuous dependence on $t \in [a, b]$, then for any $\tau \in [a, b]$ and any $\xi \in \mathbb{R}^n$ the solution of $$x'=A(t)x$$ with initial condition $\phi(\tau)=\xi$ exists for all $t$ in $[a,b]$ and is unique.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you construct a solution like $\exp(A(t))$. And  proof uniqueness by contradiction

Comment: @Fightclub1995 : This only works if all $A(s)$ and $A(t)$ commute.

Answer (score 2):

Apply the theorem of Picard-Lindelöf, first on bounded intervals then using continuation to the whole of $\Bbb R$. Note that also the matrix norm $\|A(t)\|$ is a continuous function in $t$ that is bounded on bounded intervals.

Comment: I think you need Lipschitz dependence on $t$ to apply Picard-Lindelöf?

Comment: No, you only need continuity in $t$. The Lipschitz constant is only for the fibers in $x$ direction, but wth uniform constant over all $t$.

Answer (score -1):

Let $\mathbf \Phi$ be a $n\times n$ invertible matrix. 
$$\dfrac{d\mathbf \Phi}{dt} = A(t) \mathbf \Phi$$
Multiplying both sides at right by $\mathbf x^{-1}$
$$\dfrac{d\mathbf \Phi}{dt} \mathbf \Phi^{-1}= A(t) \mathbf I$$

Integrating both sides with respect to $t$
$$\ln \mathbf \Phi = \int A(t) dt \\
\mathbf \Phi = \exp{\bigg(\int A(t) dt \bigg)}$$

Multiplying $\mathbf \Phi(t)$ by a constant vector gives a vector $\mathbf X(t)$ which satisfies your equation, and you can evaluate in $t=\tau$

I hope it helps. 
*See Boyce, DiPrima. 2012 for more information*

Comment: This only works if $A$ is constant or commuting in all times. In general $e^Ae^B\ne e^{A+B}$ resp. the corresponding logarithm formula which you are implicitly using.